# Из одного списка сделать два вложенных друг в друга. Python

Tags: python, списки

Есть список в формате:

```
list = [["f1", "object1"],["f1", "object2"],["f2", "object3"],["f2", "object4"],]
```

Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом:

```
ll = []    
for g in groupby( sorted(list,key=lambda x:x[1]) ,key=lambda x:x[1]):
    ll.append(g[0])

    for i in g[1]:
        ll.append(i[0])
```

Но на выходе получаю не совсем то, что нужно. Получаю одномерный список следующего формата:

```
list3 = ["f1", "object1", "object2", "f2", "object3", "object4"]
```

Мне необходимо его сгруппировать так, чтобы на выходе получался следующий формат

```
listGroup = [["f1", ["object1", "object2"]], ["f2", ["object3", "object4"]]]
```

Comment: Называть переменную `list` это хороший способ устроить себе марафон поиска багов. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
in_l = [["f1", "object1"], ["f1", "object2"], 
        ["f2", "object3"], ["f2", "object4"],]

from collections import defaultdict

temp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for fn, objn in in_l:
    temp_dict[fn].append(objn)

out_l = [list(item) for item in temp_dict.items()]
print(out_l)  # [['f1', ['object1', 'object2']], ['f2', ['object3', 'object4']]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Если через [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), то:

```
items = [["f1", "object1"], ["f1", "object2"], ["f2", "object3"], ["f2", "object4"]]

# В одну строку:
new_items = [[key, [x[1] for x in item_list]] for key, item_list in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x[0])]
print(new_items)


new_items = []

for key, item_list in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    new_items.append([key, [x[1] for x in item_list]])

print(new_items)
```

Иначе можно сгруппировать элементы вручную через словарь:

```
items = [["f1", "object1"], ["f1", "object2"], ["f2", "object3"], ["f2", "object4"]]

from collections import OrderedDict
key_by_item_list = OrderedDict()

for key, value in items:
    if key not in key_by_item_list:
        key_by_item_list[key] = []

    key_by_item_list[key].append(value)

print(key_by_item_list)  # OrderedDict([('f1', ['object1', 'object2']), ('f2', ['object3', 'object4'])])

# В одну строку:
new_items = [[key, item_list] for key, item_list in key_by_item_list.items()]
print(new_items)


new_items = []

for key, item_list in key_by_item_list.items():
    new_items.append([key, item_list])

print(new_items)
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение в стиле Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

In [153]: df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['c1','c2'])

In [155]: df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(list).reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[155]: [['f1', ['object1', 'object2']], ['f2', ['object3', 'object4']]]
```

Пошагово:

```
In [161]: df
Out[161]:
   c1       c2
0  f1  object1
1  f1  object2
2  f2  object3
3  f2  object4

In [162]: df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(list)
Out[162]:
c1
f1    [object1, object2]
f2    [object3, object4]
Name: c2, dtype: object

In [163]: df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(list).reset_index()
Out[163]:
   c1                  c2
0  f1  [object1, object2]
1  f2  [object3, object4]

In [164]: df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(list).reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[164]: [['f1', ['object1', 'object2']], ['f2', ['object3', 'object4']]]
```